# make command is working outside the gradle in android

Tags: android, cmake, android-gradle-plugin, gnu-make, swig

```
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    exec {
        workingDir './src/main/cpp/'
        executable 'cmd'
        args "/C"
        args "make.exe"
        args "-f"
        args "swigGenerate.mk"
    }
    exec {
        workingDir './src/main/cpp/'
        executable 'cmd'
        args "/C"
        args "make.exe"
        args "-f"
        args "swig.mk"
    }
}
```

The above gradle command inside task swigGenerate(dependsOn : "preBuild"), is working on command line when executed with make command, and is not working when the gradle is run.

I tried almost everything, need some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting the args "/C" line is removing the issue and its working properly. But according to [cmd MSDN documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771320(v=ws.11).aspx) having /c is not a problem. Still wonder why in some systems it works and other it doesn't.

Need some insights on this